# How to install OC4J 10.1.3.n server adapter to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, oc4j

I am using eclipse and tried to define a new OC4J 10.1.3.n. I installed "Eclipse web tools platform", "Oracle Enterprise Pack For Eclipse". But it did't works. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3):

OC4J support was part of Eclipse Web Tools Platform, but was dropped in recent releases. You will need to download an older version of Eclipse. Try Juno.

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/juno/sr2

Comment: Konstantin thank you. Additionally is there any way to define oc4j in eclipse luna.